# Get the last array index after a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Hi I'm trying to find the last array of $linkNumber from my for each loop as i have an image outside the foreach loop that needs the data-slide-index to be the last array plus 1. Any help how to achieve this?

```
<?php $linkNumber = 0;?>  

<?php foreach ($variables as $variable){ ?>
     <img src="$variable" data-slide-index="$linkNumber++"/>
<?php } ?>
<img src="#" data-slide-index="<?php $linkNumber + 1;?>"
```

Comment: use `array_pop()` function of php as this will get last element of array..

Comment: `count($variables) + 1` Should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we ignore that your variables won't be printed or evaluated at all for the moment; essentially what you are doing is correct. Your problem is most of your logic isn't being executed.

You need to explicitly echo variables and evaluations should be inside a PHP block, as follows

```
<?php
$linkNumber = 0;

foreach ($variables as $variable) :
    ?>
    <img src="<?= $variable; ?>" data-slide-index="<?= $linkNumber; ?>"/>
    <?php
    $linkNumber++;
endforeach;
?>

<img src="#" data-slide-index="<?= $linkNumber; ?>"
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm an idiot, i had my echo in the foreach but missed it in the one outside it ha

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?php $linkNumber = 0;?>  

<?php foreach ($variables as $variable){ ?>
 <img src="$variable" data-slide-index="$linkNumber++"/>
 <?php } ?>
 <img src="#" data-slide-index="<?php echo count($variables) + 1;?>"
```

Comment: `<img src="$variable" data-slide-index="$linkNumber++"/>` will not evalutate.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work except for some syntax issues. Eliminating these this code works for me:

```
<?php
$linkNumber = 0;

$variables = array("test", "test2");

foreach ($variables as $variable){
     echo '<img src="' . $variable . '" data-slide-index="' . $linkNumber++ . '"/>' . "\n";
}
echo '<img src="#" data-slide-index="' . $linkNumber . '">';

?>
```

http://ideone.com/01cWNg